# How To Inject Assemply Using Write Process Memory In Flutter Using Win32 Library

Tags: flutter, memory

The Following For Reading And Write Bytes (Assemply)
In Flutter It Is Hard Or I didn't Search well I Tried To Convert Assemply Code To Hex But I Did Not Do That I Can Convert It To Bytes BuT I decided To Convert The Assemply From Any Online Web Site To Hex And Keeb Work, And Like What You Know We Have To Face New Problem,
I Can Convert Assemply To Hex But Here Problem When I Try To convert
0x00727F4C: jmp 0x00727F26

Here How Can I Calcualte The OpCode Here And 
And What If The Address That I Will Jump To Him Above The Orignal Address
And The Same Thing For Reverse.

```
 String readBytes(int lpBaseAddress, {int byte = 50}) {
    // Allocate a buffer to hold the bytes
    final buffer = ffi.calloc<BYTE>(byte);

    // Read the bytes from the target process into the buffer
    Pointer<IntPtr> bytesRead = ffi.calloc<IntPtr>();

    final result = ReadProcessMemory(
      processDetails!.processHandle,
      Pointer<Int32>.fromAddress(lpBaseAddress),
      buffer,
      byte,
      bytesRead,
    );
    String asmHex = '';
    buffer.asTypedList(bytesRead.value).forEach((element) {
      asmHex += element.toHexString(8).replaceAll('0x', '');
      // print(element);
      // print(element.toHexString(8));
    });
    //con2.hex.encode(buffer.asTypedList(bytesRead.value));
    ffi.calloc.free(buffer);
    ffi.calloc.free(bytesRead);
    return asmHex;
    // // binascii.hexlify(bytes(byte_list)).decode('utf-8');
  }

  bool? writeBytes(int lpBaseAddress, String assemply, {int byte = 50}) {
    String newAssem = assemply.replaceAll('0x', '');

    // Allocate a buffer to hold the bytes
    final buffer = ffi.calloc<BYTE>(byte);
    int outerIndex = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < newAssem.length; index += 2) {
      int bytes = con2.hex.decode(newAssem.substring(index, index + 2))[0];
      buffer[outerIndex] = bytes;
      outerIndex++;
    }
    final result = WriteProcessMemory(
      processDetails!.processHandle,
      Pointer<Int32>.fromAddress(lpBaseAddress),
      buffer,
      byte,
      nullptr,
    );
    // con2.hex.decode(assemply)
    ffi.calloc.free(buffer);
    return result == 1 ? true : false;
  }
```

Comment: i Have the same problem, you need assember did you find any think ????